# Limitations for Firebase Notification Topics

Tags: firebase, firebase-notifications

I want to use Firebase notification for my android application and what i want to know is that is there any limitation for number of topics ? or for the number of users that can subscribe a topic ? 
For example can i have 10000 topics with 1 million users for each of them ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is no limitation on the number of topics or subscriptions. There was a limitation of 1 million subscriptions for the first year after topics was initially launched but that restriction was removed at this year's (2016) Google I/O. FCM now supports unlimited topics and subscribers per app. See the [docs for confirmation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

Answer (score 36):

Topic messaging supports **unlimited subscriptions** for each topic. However, FCM enforces limits in these areas:

1. One app instance can be subscribed to **no more than 2000 topics**.
2. If you are using batch import to subscribe app instances, each request is limited to 1000 app instances.
3. The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.

Check this
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: I'd like to know what "app instance" in this official docs means. Does it indicates an app such as an iOS App in a Firebase Project. Or an installed app in a smartphone device?

Comment: Its a good question. As per the Firebase document, "Instance IDs identify individual installations of your app".
From this we have to come to conclusion as  "app instance" = An installed app in a smartphone device.

Comment: @REMITH Thx a lot. I finally understood that.