# I want to know how many messages can I send with topic through FCM

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

is there limitation in sending messages with topic? For instance, let's assume there are 100000 users subscribing topic, "weather". And I want to send messages to the topic "weather". is it possible to send 100000 messages to the subscribers(100000 users) at once without any rejection?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented limit to the number of subscribers that can be added to an FCM topic. While there is probably a physical limit somewhere in the system, I haven't heard of what that would be, and there are definitely projects with well over 100K subscribers to a topic.

Also see:

- [Limitations for Firebase Notification Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829466/limitations-for-firebase-notification-topics) (which your question is actually a duplicate of, so I'll close it shortly)
- [What is the maximum limit of users for single topic subscription in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374714/what-is-the-maximum-limit-of-users-for-single-topic-subscription-in-firebase)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted to know how many messages can I send with topics.

Comment: There is no documented limit for that either. I'm not sure why you'd want to send 100K messages to each of 100K users in one go though, instead of sending a single message to each of them with the relevant data.

Comment: Our company is developing a live chat service. We think that there are always going to be possibilities to send 100K in one go in our live chat service, this is why we are considering of this case. As you suggested, sending a single message to each of them is acceptable for FCM? Furthermore is it going to be possible to send more than 1000k messages in one go?

Comment: FCM sends and delivers millions of messages each second, so another 100K won't make too much of a difference. If all 100K devices subscribe to the same topic, you can send a message to all of them with a single API call. If you want to send to device tokens, you can send batch requests of up to 500 tokens as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices